# Перебрать файлы в папках и сравнить между собой

Tags: python, ос

Это выше моего начального уровня в алгоритмах Python. Вот что пытаюсь сделать. Я пишу алгоритм сравнения файлов, содержащих голоса людей (один файл - один человек). Есть директория `Voices`, где хранятся поддиректории `spk1`, `spk2` и т.д.

Важно! В каждой поддиректории - один уникальный спикер и его разные высказывания (по 2-4 файла, т.е. по 2-4 высказывания на человека). Названия файлов унифицированы: в папке `spk1` это `spk_1_track_1.wav`, `spk_1_track_2.wav` и проч. См. рис.

[image: Структура каталога и именование файлов в его поддиректориях]

И вот незадача: как сравнивать файлы? Понимаю, что можно через регулярки, но не могу составить правильный шаблон названия файла в регулярных выражениях.

Надо вот что. Я должен обойти каждую субдиректорию и сравнить все её файлы друг с другом с помощью функции модуля speechbrain (в неё передаются по 2 файла): сначала беру первый файл субдиректории и сравниваю со всеми из этой субдиректории, затем беру второй файл и сравниваю со всеми - и так с каждым файлом. Следом перехожу к следующей субдиректории.
Если на выходе сравнения двух файлов получаю ответ True, это значит, что в этих файлах система распознала голос одного и того же человека.

Подчеркну: сравниваем только внутри каждой субдиректории. Это требуется, чтобы посчитать, как часто алгоритм ошибается, когда слышит 2 варианта голоса одного говорящего.

Итак, на выходе мне надо посчитать все True, чтобы вычислить accuracy. Для этого перед циклом созданы 2 счетчика: один считает общее число сравнений, другой - количество True. На вывод в консоль получаю их отношение - accuracy (хотя можно было бы посчитать через sklearn)

Код:

```
import os
import re 
from speechbrain.pretrained import SpeakerRecognition

num_true=0
num_total=0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Voices/'):
    
    for num, file in enumerate(files):
        verification = SpeakerRecognition.from_hparams(source="speechbrain/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb", savedir="pretrained_models/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb")
        # далее сравниваем 2 файла: здесь - конкретные, но у меня задача прописать общий шаблон;
        # причем важно, чтобы сравнение каждый раз велось внутри папки спикера
        score, prediction = verification.verify_files('Voices/spk7/spk_7_track_3.wav', 'Voices/spk8/spk_8_track_1.wav')
        num_total+=1
        if # при сравнении файлов prediction == tensor([True]):
            num_true+=1
    accuracy = num_true/num_total
    print(accuracy)
```

Установить библиотеку speechbrain достаточно просто:
`!pip install speechbrain`

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что именно вы хотите сравнить с помощью "регулярки".

Comment: @strawdog, я сравниваю фактически голоса спикеров (на данном этапе всякий раз - голос одного человека) - и так по 11-ти людям (то бишь по 11 папкам). Чтобы упростить задачу, я определил названия файлов таким образом, чтобы с помощью регулярного выражения можно было написать шаблон этих имен (уникальность каждого файла задается нумерацией папок и треков в каждой папке - все же прочие элементы повторяются).

Comment: @strawdog, сложность в том: 1) как описать шаблоном повторяющиеся элементы? 2) как описать сменные элементы (что каждый раз они разные: сравнили файлы 1 и 2, затем 1 и 3, затем, 2 и 3 и проч.) ? 3) как описать перебор файлов?

Comment: Так причем здесь регулярки? Вам коллекции нужны что-ли? то есть, ваш вопрос сводится с эффективному перебору имен файлов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вопрос сводится к эффективному перебору имен файлов, то сделать это можно с помощью комбинаций модуля itertools:

```
from itertools import combinations
a = ['spk_1_track_1.wav', 'spk_1_track_2.wav', 'spk_1_track_3.wav', 'spk_1_track_4.wav']
res = list(combinations(a, 2))
```

res:

```
[('spk_1_track_1.wav', 'spk_1_track_2.wav'),
 ('spk_1_track_1.wav', 'spk_1_track_3.wav'),
 ('spk_1_track_1.wav', 'spk_1_track_4.wav'),
 ('spk_1_track_2.wav', 'spk_1_track_3.wav'),
 ('spk_1_track_2.wav', 'spk_1_track_4.wav'),
 ('spk_1_track_3.wav', 'spk_1_track_4.wav')]
```

И даже этот вариант перебора избыточен. Но в вашем случае наиболее эффективен